# How to do a camera projection in maya?

Tags: effects, post-production, tracking, visual-effects, maya

I have a video, which I have tracked and solved for camera movement, which I have imported into maya.

Now that I have this scene, I would like to do a camera projection on the objects, however, I can only get it to work with a single image.

How can I project a video on my geometry, instead of a photo?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To project a video instead of a photo:

- convert your video to an image sequence (with Nuke, AfterFX, Premiere, whatever...)
- load it into your file node, then click on 'Use Image Sequence'
- scroll in the timeline, and Maya will load the according frame